# SQL INSERT INTO avoiding duplicates on specific fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I currently have a SQL insert into statement that copies items from one identical table to another.

The source table has many identical records or records that may have small variations.

Example...

The source and destination table are in the format:

```
ItemDATE // ItemTIME // SITENAME // SERIAL_NO // RPM // Power // Voltage1 // Voltage2 // etc
```

The source may contain:

```
ItemDATE // ItemTIME // SITENAME // SERIAL_NO // RPM // Power // Voltage1 // Voltage2 // etc

2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 // 17:00:00.1 // Oxford College // 0014617 // 1500 // 250 // 250.8 // 249.2
2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 // 17:00:00.1 // Oxford College // 0014617 // 1499// 249 // 253.5 // 240.6
2013-01-01 00:00:00.000 // 17:00:00.1 // Oxford College // 0014617 // 1502// 251 // 239.8 // 269.8
```

My insert statement is:

```
INSERT INTO ReportingSystem.dbo.HistoryLog(ItemDATE, ItemTIME, SITENAME, SERIAL_NO, RPM, Power, Voltage1, Voltage2)
SELECT ItemDATE, ItemTIME, SITENAME, SERIAL_SN, RPM, Power, Voltage1, Voltage2      
FROM ReportingSystem.dbo.RTCU

EXCEPT
SELECT ItemDATE, ItemTIME, SITENAME, SERIAL_SN, RPM, Power, Voltage1, Voltage2
FROM ReportingSystem.dbo.HistoryLog
```

Where HistoryLog is the destination and RTCU is the source.

I am not concerned about the different values in the RPM, Power, Voltage1 and Voltage2 fields but there should be no records where the itemDATE, ItemTIME, SITENAME and SERIAL_NO are the same.

But with the Except statement I am still getting duplicated as it considers the entire record.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
INSERT INTO HistoryLog
(ItemDATE, ItemTIME, SITENAME, SERIAL_NO, RPM, Power, Voltage1, Voltage2)

SELECT ItemDATE, ItemTIME, SITENAME, SERIAL_NO, RPM, Power, Voltage1, Voltage2
FROM RTCU
WHERE not exists (select * from HistoryLog
WHERE HistoryLog.ItemDATE = rtcu.ItemDATE
and HistoryLog.ItemTIME = rtcu.ItemTIME
and HistoryLog.SITENAME = rtcu.SITENAME 
and HistoryLog.SERIAL_NO= rtcu.SERIAL_NO
);
```

Please help....

Comment: So what value do you want stored for Voltage1, Voltage2, etc.? If you only want one row with the other distinct values, you need to tell SQL Server how to pick the rest.

Comment: It doesn't matter I am not concerned about the specific values for these as long as they are not NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.HistoryLog
(
  ItemDATE, ItemTIME, 
  SITENAME, SERIAL_NO, 
  RPM, Power, Voltage1, Voltage2
)
SELECT 
  ItemDATE, ItemTIME, 
  SITENAME, SERIAL_NO, 
  RPM, Power, Voltage1, Voltage2
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    ItemDATE, ItemTIME, 
    SITENAME, SERIAL_NO, 
    RPM, Power, Voltage1, Voltage2,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
      PARTITION BY ItemDATE, ItemTIME, 
        SITENAME, SERIAL_NO
      ORDER BY RPM DESC
    )
  FROM dbo.RTCU
) AS RTCU
WHERE rn = 1
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.HistoryLog
    WHERE ItemDATE  = rtcu.ItemDATE
      AND ItemTIME  = rtcu.ItemTIME
      AND SITENAME  = rtcu.SITENAME 
      AND SERIAL_NO = rtcu.SERIAL_NO
);
```

Comment: Perfect thank you @AaronBertrand tested and working with no duplicates :D :D you've saved me a lot of head scratchin...

Answer (score 0):

Your last query should work fine. Does `ItemDATE` or other 3 accept `NULL` values? They could not be compared with `=`, e.g.

```
(HistoryLog.ItemDATE = rtcu.ItemDATE or HistoryLog.ItemDATE is null and rtcu.ItemDATE is null)
```

Is collation is case-sensitive? If so, strings with different cases would not be compared as intended. Use `COLLATE` to specify another collation, e.g.:

```
HistoryLog.SITENAME = rtcu.SITENAME COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
```

Comment: The join is working fine. It's producing too many rows, not too few.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I understood. Look this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15dec/3 nulls should be handled directly. In case of example it should be `(s.Date = snd.Date or s.Date is null and snd.Date is null)`. I can write another sample for collation.

Comment: Again, NULLs are not the problem, nor is anything that results in "not matching." The matching is working fine, the OP is trying to ***eliminate*** two of the three rows. All of the solutions you're presenting attempt to solve a different problem (rows are missing).

Comment: When running the insert into it inserts all duplicates into the HistoryLog table as they were never present in the HistoryLog table before execution.

Comment: @Neil can you please address the comment I added to the question? All of these solutions are going astray because your requirements are not clear. Of the three rows you showed in the sample data, which one do you want to keep and why?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Lets say for example which ever one has the highest RPM value, but it doesn't really matter which one for its purpose.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You right, I forgot that dups are already in a source table. My bad.

Comment: @Neil ok, highest RPM is something you can actually write a deterministic query for... please see my answer.